# Manipulate DOM in SWT Browser (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, eclipse, dom, browser, swt

I am working on a prototype that embeds an HTML page inside an eclipse view through the use of SWT Browser widget. We are working using eclipse 3.8.2 as the target platform.

The HTML page invokes some methods for manipulating the DOM such as innerHTML, createElement, appendChild.

Even though this HTML page seems to work fine on a regular browser (Firefox 38 esr is the one I am using). The same page embedded in the SWT Browser does not change the DOM model. The javascript functions called from the HTML page are written in an external Javascript module.

The browser has Javascript enabled ;-)

Any hint about what to do for having the browser properly working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to inline some JavaScript so see if it works at all? Where exactly is the JavaScript loaded from. A standalone snippet would also help to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I still have not found a solution but I think there is something related with styles. I was using bootstrap for laying out the elements, so I got nothing visible. I explicitely sized the componets (width and height) and they became visible.

Comment: We're no magicians, please show a minimal standalone example to reproduce the issue.